# Why is my domain accepting anything after it in Silverstripe?

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

Why is my domain accepting anything after it in Silverstripe and not issuing a 404?  For example, www.mydomain.com/jsdkjdsk, www.mydomain.com/ksjdjs.htnk, www.mydomain.com/jj, etc. when I defined my routes and controller like in the docs example,

routes:

```
---
Name: mysiteroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'team//$Action/$ID/$Name': 'TeamController'
```

Controller:

```
class TeamController extends Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'players',
        'index'
    );

    public function index(HTTPRequest $request) {
        // ..
    }

    public function players(HTTPRequest $request) {
        print_r($request->allParams());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that your example code is related to your issue. If you remove the above, do the URLs still work? My first guess is that you have some other rules, either in `Director.rules` or in your `.htaccess`?